# How to order a dictionary based on values which is a list?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'elmo': [4, 3], 'elsa': [4, 2], 'legos': [0, 0], 'drone': [1, 1], 'tablet': [0, 0], 'warcraft': [1, 1]}
```

Now, the values mean this:
The word elmo has appeared the most overall in all the quotes and it has been quoted in 3 quotes.
Now, both elmo and elsa are quoted 4 times but elmo must come first as it has been quoted in more number of quotes.
I have to get an output like this given the top most n frequent words required
If n = 2, then it must return
['elmo', 'elsa']
Had there been just one value like this:

```
{'elmo': 4, 'elsa': 4, 'legos': 0, 'drone': 1, 'tablet': 0, 'warcraft': 1}
```

I will convert this to a list like this:

```
arr = [('elmo', 4), ('elsa', 4), ('legos', 0) ...]
```

And then I will do this:

```
return [x for x, _ in sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

So, this will be easy. But now there are two values like [4, 3] etc. How to do with two values for the key keyword in sort()?

## EDIT:

Now, assume my dictionary is:

```
{'coach': [9, 7], 'make': [15, 9], 'modern': [9, 8], 'suggest': [4, 4], 'behavior': [11, 10], 'past': [12, 10], 'affect': [5, 5], 'billion': [5, 4], 'nor': [11, 10], 'last': [9, 8]}
```

If I do this:

```
r = [(k, v) for k, v in zip(word_map.keys(), word_map.values())]
r.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
return [t for t, _ in r]
```

(where word_map is my dictionay name)
I must get:

```
['past', 'behavior', 'nor', 'make', 'modern', 'last', 'coach', 'affect',  'billion','suggest']
```

But instead I get this:

```
['behavior', 'past', 'nor', 'make', 'modern', 'last', 'coach', 'affect', 'suggest', 'billion']
```

Comment: You could sort it by list element 1 and then find values with the same list element 1 and then sort them by list element 2. I can post the code as an answer if you want to know how it will look.

Comment: When you compare lists, it compares the elements in order. So you should get the desired result.

Comment: Convert it to a list like `arr = [('elmo', [4, 3]), ('elsa', [4, 2]), ('legos', [0, 0]) ...]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list comprehension` and `unpacking`:

```
>>> d = {'elmo': [4, 3], 'elsa': [4, 2], 'legos': [0, 0], 'drone': [1, 1], 'tablet': [0, 0], 'warcraft': [1, 1]}
>>> [name for name, (q1, q2) in d.items() if q2 >= 2]
['elmo', 'elsa']
```

To sort:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x:d[x], reverse=True)
['elmo', 'elsa', 'drone', 'warcraft', 'legos', 'tablet']
```

According to the *EDIT*:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x:(d[x][1], d[x][0]), reverse=True)
# or, sorted(d, key=lambda x:[*d[x]][::-1], reverse=True)
['past', 'behavior', 'nor', 'make', 'modern', 'last', 'coach', 'affect', 'billion', 'suggest']
```

Comment: @JohnBrookfields there you go

Answer (score 0):

while converting to a list of tuples,  store it in the format `arr = [('elmo', 4), ('elsa', 4), ('legos', 0) ...]` bye storing `0th` element of the value in key:value pair in dict.

```
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    arr.append((k,v[0]))

return [x for x, _ in sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'elmo': [4, 3], 'elsa': [4, 2], 'legos': [0, 0], 'drone': [1, 1], 'tablet': [0, 0], 'warcraft': [1, 1]}

output = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k,v:(k[0], k[1]), reverse=True)
output = [x[0] for x in output][0:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having the sort key be a tuple?

```py
data = {
  'coach': [9, 7], 
  'make': [15, 9], 
  'modern': [9, 8], 
  'suggest': [4, 4], 
  'behavior': [11, 10], 
  'past': [12, 10], 
  'affect': [5, 5], 
  'billion': [5, 4], 
  'nor': [11, 10], 
  'last': [9, 8]
}
sorted_data = sorted(
  data.items(), 
  reverse=True, 
  key=lambda item: (item[1][1], item[1][0])
)
sorted_keys = [x[0] for x in sorted_data]
```